# Is there a way to download photos from Google photos that match a certain pattern/style?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, ocr, tesseract, google-photos

I have a large number of photos stored in Google Photos. I'd like to download (only) those that are screenshots I took from Instagram profiles in order to organize them locally (group photos of the same profile into the same folder).

I think the following would be necessary:

1. Log into Google
2. Iterate over images
3. Match each photo to a "pattern"
4. Download it
5. Run OCR and move it to a folder

I assume this should be possible to realize with Python. Step 3 is the one, I am really struggling with. Does anyone have a hint on how this could be done? Or is there even a tool out there that helps me doing, what I'd like to do? :)

Comment: what do you mean `match pattern`? If you mean to compare with other image then you have to first download it.

Comment: I am only interested in screenshots I took from Instagram. So each image has to be "match" the "pattern" for an Instagram screenshot, i.e. e.g. a username in the upper and a "comment" field in the lower area of the image. Just to clarify: Downloading is not that of a problem for me - I could just simply delete the image that does not "fit" to the "pattern" afterwards. The recognition of an image being a screenshot of interest is the difficult part, I think.

Comment: it still to need to download it and detect it all on local computer. Google Photo doesn't have function for this. And it may need `OCR` to check if there is text in corners. I don't use Instagram and I don't know how looks "screenshot" and I have no idea if there is better method to recognize it. I would check if it add some element on all images, or if it has some `"meta data"` in file.